# list first and last name in combo box from a sql table

Tags: wpf

I have a combo box in wpf and I want to list first and last name in from a sql table. It is only allowing one entry at a time. Also I want to give each a heading but ValueMemberPath not recognised.

```
private void displayCust()
    {
        using (Entities c = new Entities())
        {
            cbUsers.ItemsSource = c.Customer.ToList();
            //cbUsers.ValueMemberPath = "First";
            cbUsers.DisplayMemberPath = "First";
            cbUsers.DisplayMemberPath = "Last";
        }

    }
```

Comment: In Customer create a public property fullname and combine there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the easiest way to do what you want is for you to `override` the `ToString()` method in your `customer` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
}
```

Then you could do this:

```
using (Entities c = new Entities())
{
    cbUsers.ItemsSource = c.Customer.ToList();
}
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
using (Entities c = new Entities())
{
    cbUsers.ItemsSource = c.Customer.Select(c => string.Format("{0} {1}", c.FirstName, 
        c.LastName)).ToList();
}
```

However this will result in plain `string` values being entered into the `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

@Sheridan solution is a good solution.

Anyway, if you don't want to have a property that combines both (as @Blam said), you could also have an item template for the combobox with a MultiValueConverter.

Take a look at: http://blog.csainty.com/2009/12/wpf-multibinding-and.html

This way, the itemssource of the combobox can be the Customer class and you can do "things" with it, instead of being a plain string.

Regards,